# How do I send email from within Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to send an email from my Symfony project from within a Docker container.

I have installed [Bytemark SMTP](https://hub.docker.com/r/bytemark/smtp/) running the command `docker pull bytemark/smtp`

I am using Mailtrap.io to send the email, they provide the relevant `MAILER_DSN` string to enable email for Symfony:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://username:password@smtp.mailtrap.io:2525?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login
```

I am getting this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host "smtp.mailtrap.io:2525": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again
```

In my Docker compose file:

```
mail:
  image: bytemark/smtp
  restart: always
  environment:
    RELAY_HOST: smtp.mailtrap.io
    RELAY_PORT: 587
    RELAY_USERNAME: username
    RELAY_PASSWORD: password
```

These are my docker images:

```
bob@DESKTOP-QSCSABV:/mnt/c/dev$ docker images
REPOSITORY       TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
kooldev/php      7.4-nginx      60dffeeb4345   5 days ago     296MB
kooldev/php      7.4            dd84a53ace7d   5 days ago     278MB
kooldev/php      8.0-nginx      12e065b8713e   5 days ago     297MB
composer         latest         c69d012e5132   9 days ago     176MB
mysql            8.0            c60d96bd2b77   10 days ago    514MB
php              7.3-apache     666b66927747   11 days ago    411MB
mariadb          10.1           895244a22f37   3 months ago   352MB
hello-world      latest         d1165f221234   4 months ago   13.3kB
docker/compose   1.28.0         9bdf435c575a   6 months ago   76.6MB
bytemark/smtp    latest         cd5c77c3bcd8   3 years ago    130MB
php              7.2.1-apache   f99d319c7004   3 years ago    377MB
bob@DESKTOP-QSCSABV:/mnt/c/dev$
```

I've read that I need to link the containers, but the `--link` option is legacy and that `user-defined networks` is now recommended.  Is this what I need to do?  Can anyone help me out with an example?